# Are these unix exe files and others 32-bit code, & should I do something about them before moving to Catalina?

Tags: macos, unix, catalina, 32-bit

I am running Mojave 10.14.6  (on a late 2013 MacBook Pro), waiting to upgrade to Catalina.  Checking for 32bit applications lead to a list containing

```
/System/Library/Frameworks/DiscRecording.framework/Versions/A/Resources/draudiotool
/System/Library/Frameworks/AppKitScripting.framework/Versions/A/AppKitScripting
/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/vmutils.framework/Versions/A/vmutils
/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CoreMediaPrivate.framework/Versions/A/CoreMediaPrivate
```

(which seem to be mostly Unix executable files), some dynamic libraries, a few apps, and then some items like this

```
/sbin/autodiskmount
/usr/sbin/pictd
/usr/lib/libnetsnmp.5.2.1.dylib
/usr/bin/qc2movie
```

Are these 32-bit code files that are going to block the use of apps, even if the apps are 64-bit?  Will installing Catalina remove them, or should I delete them first?  I can delete the apps (don’t need or can upgrade them), but is there anything I can do ahead of time with this list?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The content of `/System` as well as all files in `/sbin`, `/usr/sbin`, `/usr/lib` and `/usr/bin` is part of a macOS installation and will be replaced/upgraded if/when you upgrade to Catalina.

Comment: Does the same apply to    /Library   files?

Comment: @abovdal It depends :-) Files there are installed by macOS as well as by applications, but usually this should be obvious based on the folder/file names.